# What is the purpose of --plugin parameter in protoc command

Tags: protocol-buffers, proto3

I am currently working in Protobuf part, and using protoc compiler to compile `.proto` file to java classes. In this command we have a paramter called '`plugin`' used as `--plugin=EXECUTABLE`. I went through official documentation which says

> Specifies a plugin executable to use.
>                                 Normally, protoc searches the PATH for
>                                 plugins, but you may specify additional
>                                 executables not in the path using this flag.
>                                 Additionally, EXECUTABLE may be of the form
>                                 NAME=PATH, in which case the given plugin name
>                                 is mapped to the given executable even if
>                                 the executable's own name differs.

But Still I am not able to get the exact usecase to leverage this parameter. Kindly help.

Reference: I went through https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.compiler.plugin

Answer (score 1):

The `--plugin` option is useful for when you need to generate code for frameworks that builds on top of Protobuf. One notable example is [gRPC](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/java/generated-code/). You would invoke `protoc` with the gRPC plugin for Java like this:

```
protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc-java --grpc-java_out="$OUTPUT_FILE" --proto_path="$DIR_OF_PROTO_FILE" "$PROTO_FILE"
```